# Spring: "Authentication object cannot be null" when creating MongoDB index programmatically

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-security, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to create an index (@CompoundIndex to be precise) like described in 'Example 186' in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.4.11/reference/html/#mapping.index-creation.

This is exactly how I try it:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void initIndicesAfterStartup() {

        MappingContext<? extends MongoPersistentEntity<?>, MongoPersistentProperty> mappingContext = mongoTemplate
            .getConverter().getMappingContext();

        IndexResolver resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(mappingContext);

        IndexOperations indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(MyDomainObject.class);
        resolver.resolveIndexFor(MyDomainObject.class).forEach(indexOps::ensureIndex);
    }
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authentication object cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.<init>(SecurityExpressionRoot.java:76)
    at org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension$1.<init>(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:124)
    at org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.getRootObject(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:124)
    at org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.getRootObject(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider$EvaluationContextExtensionAdapter.<init>(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:415)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.lambda$toAdapters$3(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:202)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.toAdapters(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:203)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.access$000(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider$ExtensionAwarePropertyAccessor.<init>(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.doGetEvaluationContext(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:131)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContext(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContext(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getEvaluationContext(BasicPersistentEntity.java:557)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity.getEvaluationContext(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:219)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.getEvaluationContextForProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:664)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.resolveCompoundIndexKeyFromStringDefinition(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.createCompoundIndexDefinition(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:437)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.createCompoundIndexDefinitions(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:427)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.potentiallyCreateCompoundIndexDefinitions(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.resolveIndexForEntity(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:127)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.resolveIndexFor(MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.IndexResolver.resolveIndexFor(IndexResolver.java:79)
    at com.mytest.MongoConfiguration.initIndicesAfterStartup(MongoConfiguration.java:38)
```

Obviously some code wants an Authentication object from the security context for some reason.
I don't have a security context at that very time as I want to create the index automatically without user interference.

I'm using spring boot 2.7.11 and spring-data-mongodb 3.4.11.

I can make that whole thing work by running these lines first before everything else in the `initIndicesAfterStartup()`:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq
            = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("dummy_user", "dummy_pwd");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authReq);
```

Is there a way I can disable the SecurityEvaluationContextExtension which obviously tries to add the Authentication object to the evaluation context? I didn't find a way at least.

I'd appreciate any ideas on that.